# Facebook bot redirect for angular app showing card title as 302 redirect

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, facebook-share

I followed this blog 
http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app
for enabling rich sharing and there by changed my **.htaccess** file to redirect facebook crawler to a custom **story.php**

Here's the **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/story.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Everything in **story.php** and **.htaccess** is working fine because when i replace the *www.website.com* with another staging instance in which **story.php** exists, voila it works but when it comes to same url redirect its showing this disturbing image upon sharing
[image]

I exhausted all kind of open graph meta tags

```
property="og:title"
property="og:description"
property="og:image"
property="og:site_name"
property="fb:app_id"
```

Any help would be of help because redirecting it to another instance is showing that instance's ip in caption of fb card. And unfortunately there's no caption meta tag.